# Getting 'Invalid Boolean' error while inserting a file to influx's measurement through shell

Tags: shell, influxdb

I'm trying to insert a file to influx through shell script using write API. Inconsistently data is not getting inserted. I get 'Invalid Boolean' response whenever its failing to insert to influx.

Kindly help me in identifying where i'm doing the mistake

Here is my code to write to influx

```
curl -s -X POST "http://influxdb:8186/write?db=mydb" --data-binary @data.txt
```

I get below json response with an error very inconsistently.

I'm generating the data.txt file with after some calculation. Below is the screenshot of the file.

[image]

```
{"error":"unable to parse 'databackupstatus1,env=engg-az-dev2 tenant=dataplatform snapshot_name=engg-az-dev2-dataplatform-2019-07-08_12-43-59 state=Started backup_status=Not-Applicable': invalid boolean\nunable to parse 'databackupstatus1,env=engg-az-dev2 tenant=dataplatform snapshot_name=engg-az-dev2-dataplatform-2019-07-08_12-43-59 state=Completed backup_status=\"SUCCESS\"': invalid boolean"}
```

Note : The same data above had got inserted multiple times

Comment: Could show the measurement schema, specifically the fields?

Comment: Nikolay, i was able to solve my problem. Unknowingly i was sending field as string, with further more research go to know it has to be an integer.